# How to give a general solution to this ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve this ODE of first order:
$$ (2y^2 +6xy-x^2) dx +(y^2+4xy+3x^2) dy=0 $$

because of

$ P(x,y)= 2y^2+6xy-x^2 \rightarrow_{  \partial y} =4y+6x $

$ Q(x,y)= y^2+4xy+3x^3 \rightarrow_{ \partial x} = 4y+6x $
the ODE is exact.

Determining the Integrants:

$F(x,y)= \int P(x,y) dx = 2y^2x+3x^2y- \frac{1}{3} x^3 +C_1 $

and

$ F(x,y)= \int Q(x,y) dy= \frac{1}{3}y^3 + 2xy^2+3x^2y +C_2 $

I would know how to determine a solution with initial values, but what do I need to do to determine the general solution of this ODE?

I just saw that there already exists a Question on this differential equation...but I don't get why $ F(x,y)= c $

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

$$F(x,y) = 2y^2x+3x^2y- \frac{1}{3} x^3 +C_1(y)$$
$$F(x,y)=  \frac{1}{3}y^3 + 2xy^2+3x^2y +C_2(x)$$
Then the solution is:
$$2y^2x+3x^2y- \frac{1}{3} (x^3-y^3) =C$$